# How to stop hibernate excessive logging?

Tags: java, hibernate

My application uses hibernate and its printing lot of logging.
I tried to set logging to error level as below. However, it does not set hibernate logging to error level. 
Is anything missing here?

**pom.xml :**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-jul</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**log4j2.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration status="INFO">

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="[%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss}] [%-5p] [%t] [%C{1}:%M:%L] - %m%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.myapp" level="error" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="org.hibernate" level="error" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
        </Logger>

    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

**Hibernate and spring version used :**

```
<spring-framework.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
        <hibernate.version>3.6.9.Final</hibernate.version>
```

**Log its printing**

```
19:05:16.733 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter - throwQueryException() : no errors
19:05:16.734 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG o.h.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - HQL: SELECT g FROM myClass g
19:05:16.734 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG o.h.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - SQL: sql sample
19:05:16.734 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter - throwQueryException() : no errors
19:05:16.734 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG o.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl - Checking named query: Underlyer.findAll
19:05:16.735 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG o.h.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - parse() - HQL: SELECT u FROM entity.class1 u
19:05:16.737 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST - --- HQL AST ---
 \-[QUERY] Node: 'query'
    \-[SELECT_FROM] Node: 'SELECT_FROM'
       +-[FROM] Node: 'FROM'
       |  \-[RANGE] Node: 'RANGE'
       |     +-[DOT] Node: '.'
       |     |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
       |     |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
       |     |  |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
       |     |  |  |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
       |     |  |  |  |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
```

Comment: `appender-ref` should be `AppenderRef`.

Comment: Look at [this](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/how-to-configure-hibernate-logging-with-log4j2).

Comment: where you placed your log4j.xml config file?

Answer (score 6):

The thread names seem to suggest that you're running on a weblogic container. Are you sure that the logging config is being used at all? (e.g. see [log4j2-not-working-in-weblogic-12-2-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35766959/log4j2-not-working-in-weblogic-12-2-1)).

Apart from that, I also don't see the point in using additivity="false" and then repeating exactly the same appenders. Why don't you prefer something simpler like this?

```
<Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </Root>
    <Logger name="com.myapp" level="error"/>
    <Logger name="org.hibernate" level="error"/>
</Loggers>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it a Spring application if so you could hide SQL from printing via properties file option:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
```

If it is not a Spring you could try this (in Sprint apllication such Hibernate log config works):

```
<Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="error"/>
<Logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="error"/>
```

OR whatever Log Level do you want.

Answer (score 1):

Set the hibernate Configuration properties:

```
hibernate.show_sql=false
```

Answer (score 0):

What seems that your logger is not picking the right file configuration, there might be two reasons.

1. You did not specify your **log4j2.xml** file path correctly, as your project is not picking it right, which is detected from your logs.
2. Your **log4j2.xml** file has some error in appender reference tag inside root tag, change ***appender-ref*** to ***AppenderRef***

---

```
<Root level="info">
     <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</Root>
```

to

```
<Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
</Root>
```

The above two identified reasons are from the logging pattern you are using in your **log4j2.xml** and actual logs shared are totally different. Look your desired pattern layout from **log4j2.xml**

```
<PatternLayout pattern="[%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss}] [%-5p] [%t] [%C{1}:%M:%L] - %m%n" />
```

It should print logs looks like

```
[16 Apr 2020 19:05:16.733] [...] [...] [...:...:...] - .......
```

where actual logs have different patterns.

```
19:05:16.733 [...] ... ....... - .....
```

as mentioned under.

```
19:05:16.733 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter - throwQueryException() : no errors
19:05:16.734 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG o.h.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - HQL: SELECT g FROM myClass g
19:05:16.734 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG o.h.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - SQL: sql sample
```