# LogManager ClassNotFoundException when upgrade Log4j to Logj42

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, classnotfoundexception

I should upgrade my projects log4j to log4j2.So i deleted log4j dependencies and add log4j2.Some project worked well but one project get error as follow:

```
]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager
    at jsp_servlet.__view._jspService(__view.java:86)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:35)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1029)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:104)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I used mvn dependency:tree command and tried to find some conflict between dependencies and
i tried to exclude every child library that might be relevant,but still get same error.

code :

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(View.class);
```

dependencies:

```
Maven: commons-io:commons-io:2.8.0
Maven: javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5
Maven: oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.3
Maven: org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.14.0
Maven: org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.14.0
Maven: org.apache.pdfbox:fontbox:2.0.23
Maven: org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:2.0.23
Maven: org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.12.RELEASE
Maven: org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.12.RELEASE
Maven: org.springframework:spring-web:5.2.12.RELEASE
```

log4j2.properties:

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig

#Make sure to change log file path as per your need
property.filename = path/to/filename

filters = threshold

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug

appenders = console,rolling

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %5p - %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %F:%L - %m%n

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = '-'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %5p - %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %F:%L - %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 20

loggers = rolling

#Make sure to change the package structure as per your application

logger.rolling.name = com.thy.dvs
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Comment: `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.14.0` should contain `org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager` so maybe it's not so much a dependency conflict as a packaging error?

Comment: sorry for not adding which server i'm working on.I use weblogic server.@JeroenSteenbeeke

Comment: Ah, perhaps it is this issue then? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35774403/8819761

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem at least as below picture.
When I add new dependency to pom.xml, I also had to add dependencies "available elements" to my ear/war packages.

[image]